# storing and using markup in jquery returned from an Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would welcome any comments on my method of handling the response to an Ajax request that contains html. I have php code on the server that simply outputs anchor links for a photo gallery. There can be a lot of them, maybe 1000 or so. I am using .each(function ()) on the data returned to push the markup into an array. I can then use this array later to output a subset gallery without the need for another Ajax call. I suspect the .each function is doing a lot of work building a node from returned data? I then extract the outerHTML before storing that and also building up a html string in nout for some initial output during the storing.... this does work as I want but it seems very slow, and on mobile it seems particularly slow. How would you recommend tackling this in a more efficient way? 
Many thanks for any advice on the code snippet below.

```
"use strict";

let icnt = 0;
let scrollInx = 0;
const pageImgs = 100;
const galMarkup = [];
let albumUrl = '/myserver/mypath/myalbum';  

$("#ajax-spinner").show();  

// GET Ajax content for gallery 
$.get(albumUrl, 
    {index: 0,
     numImgs: 1500},
    function(data){ 
        if(data !== ''){
            let nout = '';
            $(data).each(function (){
                let n = $(this)[0].outerHTML;
                galMarkup.push(n);

                if(++icnt <= pageImgs){ 
                    nout += n;
                    scrollInx++; 
                }
            });

            console.log("stored ", icnt, " total markup items all albums");                     

            if (nout !== '') $("#gallery").html(nout);                  
        }else{ 
            $("#gallery").html("<p>0 photos</p>");
        }
    })
    .always(function() {
        $("#ajax-spinner").hide();
     });
```

Comment: The most efficient way to generate HTML is server side.  Have your php code return the desired HTML directly.  If you need paging, page server side or hide/show the paging parts as required (if you feel the ajax requests are what's making it slower rather than the huge data load).

Comment: Also, `$(this)[0].outerHTML` can be just `this.outHTML` - no need to instantiate a jquery object just to immediately unwrap it.

Comment: Looks like your `data` is already an array (if not, can you make it one?) so no need to push to another array.